# How to query data from 3 documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have three documents of **apartment, building and basic_amenities**. i want to retrieve the data of apartment basic_amenities. usually the apartment lies in building so the basic_amenities of building and apartment are same. using these three documents how can i retrieve a data of apartment basic _amenities? here is my code

```
db.property.find({"building.apartment_id" : "a1"}),
db.property.find({"basic_amenities.property_id" : "b2"});
```

is this query is right?

here is my documents

Apartment:

```
{
    "_id" : "a1",
    "apartment" : {
        "sale_type" : "rental",
        "owner_name " : "ram sunder",
        "address" : {
            "street" : "alphornstrasse",
            "plot_no" : 54,
            "city" : "mannheim",
            "state" : "baden württemberg",
            "country" : "germany",
            "postal_code" : 68169,
            "email" : " ram.sunder@gmail.com"
        },
        "total_area" : "120 sq meters",
        "rental_price(EUR)" : {
            "monthly" : 700,
            "available_date" : ISODate("2005-03-15T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "deposit_amount" : 2100
        },
        "features" : {
            "floor" : 3,
            "rooms" : 2,
            "kitchen" : 1,
            "bathroom" : 1,
            "heating" : true,
            "garden" : true,
            "furnished" : true
        },
        "kid_condition" : "one kid"
    }
```

}

```
Building:

{
    "_id" : "b2",
    "building" : {
        "building_name" : "sai durga",
        "available_apartments" : {
            "1bhk" : 3,
            "2bhk" : 4
        },
        "owner_name" : "umang dosi",
        "address" : {
            "street" : "alphornstrasse",
            "plot_no" : 54,
            "city" : "mannheim",
            "state" : "baden württemberg",
            "country" : "germany",
            "postal_code" : 68169,
            "email" : "umang123@gmail.com"
        },
        "total_area" : "1100 sq meters",
        "apartment_id" : [ 
            "a2", 
            "a1"
        ],
        "features" : {
            "no_of_apartments" : 64,
            "community_hall" : 1,
            "garden" : 2,
            "office_room" : 1,
            "swimming_pool" : true,
            "security_cameras" : true,
            "parking" : true,
            "play_ground" : false
        }
    }
}

Basic_amenities:
{
    "_id" : "ba-b2",
    "basic_amenities" : {
        "property_id" : "b2",
        "hospital " : 10,
        "restaurant" : 3,
        "airport" : 56,
        "bahn_station" : 5,
        "city_center" : 6,
        "public_transp_type" : [ 
            "bus", 
            "tram", 
            "train"
        ],
        "future_activity" : "constructing kpmg software company"
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how to query this one?

Regards
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

I think your documents are too normalized and are improperly organized in one collection. Split apartments and buildings into an `aparments` and `buildings` collection, respectively. You can also flatten the structure of the documents because it will be redundant: you don't need to wrap all the non-`_id` fields of an `apartments` document in an `apartment` embedded document. `basic_amenities` are a property of a building, so store the amenities as part of the building:

```
{
    "_id" : "b2",
    "building_name" : "sai durga",
    "available_apartments" : {
        "1bhk" : 3,
        "2bhk" : 4
    },
    "owner_name" : "umang dosi",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "alphornstrasse",
        "plot_no" : 54,
        "city" : "mannheim",
        "state" : "baden württemberg",
        "country" : "germany",
        "postal_code" : 68169,
        "email" : "umang123@gmail.com"
    },
    "total_area" : "1100 sq meters",
    "apartment_id" : [ 
        "a2", 
        "a1"
    ],
    "features" : {
        "no_of_apartments" : 64,
        "community_hall" : 1,
        "garden" : 2,
        "office_room" : 1,
        "swimming_pool" : true,
        "security_cameras" : true,
        "parking" : true,
        "play_ground" : false
    },
    "basic_amenities" : {
        "property_id" : "b2",
        "hospital " : 10,
        "restaurant" : 3,
        "airport" : 56,
        "bahn_station" : 5,
        "city_center" : 6,
        "public_transp_type" : [ 
            "bus", 
            "tram", 
            "train"
        ],
        "future_activity" : "constructing kpmg software company"
    }
}
```

Put a reference to the containing building in the apartment document:

```
{
    "_id" : "a1",
    "building_id" : "b2",
    "sale_type" : "rental",
    "owner_name " : "ram sunder",
    ....
}
```

Use the reference to find the amenities for an apartment, which are exactly the amenities for its containing building:

```
function getAptAmenities(apt_doc) {
    bldg = db.buildings.findOne({ "_id" : apt_doc.building_id })
    if (bldg === null) return null
    return bldg.basic_amenities
}
```